# Bad characters printed in a queue in C

Tags: c, printing, queue

I'm trying to print a queue with a char array in its struct.
I just read a text file with some web address, push into the queue and try to print. The first 4 lines are ok but then it begin to print bad characters in almost all the others. I don't know whats going on. Even if I print direcly the char array from fgets it is correctly printed and the queue is correctly printed as well, so...I'm confused...

Any idea?

Here is the relevant code:

structs:

```
typedef struct n_queue {
    char *web;
    struct n_queue *next;
} QUEUE_NODE, *P_QUEUE_NODE;

typedef struct k_queue {
    P_QUEUE_NODE head;
    P_QUEUE_NODE tail;
} kind_queue;
```

Reading the file:

```
void readFile(kind_queue *q) {
    char data[9][150];
    FILE *f=fopen("list.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) perror("Web list couldn't be found.");
    int j =0;
    int i;

    while (fgets(data[j],150, f)!=NULL) {
            //If I uncomment the line below, both char array and char array in queue
            //are printed allright
        //printf("%s", data[j]);

            //Supress the new line char
        for (i=0;i<150;i++) {
            if (data[j][i] == '\n') {
                data[j][i]='\0';
                break;
            }
        }

        push_queue(q, data[j]);
        j++;
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Push code:

```
void push_queue(kind_queue *q, char *web){
    P_QUEUE_NODE p;
    p = (P_QUEUE_NODE) malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_NODE));
    p->next = NULL;
    p->web = web;
    if (is_empty(q)) q->tail = q->head = p;
    else{
        q->tail->next= p;
        q->tail = p;
    }
}
```

Main function:

```
int main () {

    kind_queue queue, *pt_queue_struct;
    pt_queue_struct = &queue;
    pt_queue_struct = init_queue(pt_queue_struct);
    readFile(&queue);

    print_queue(&queue);

    return(0);
}
```

And finally the print function:

```
void print_queue(kind_queue *q) {
    P_QUEUE_NODE paux;
    int j=1;
    for (paux=q->head; paux != NULL; paux=paux->next) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", j, paux->web);
        j++;
    }
}
```

REAL TXT:

```
http://www.google.es
http://stackoverflow.com
http://www.facebook.com
http://akinator.com/cea
http://developer.android.com/map
http://tirsa.es/65/65.htm
http://www.ufo.es/
http://thisty.com/init/
http://damned-c.me/
```

OUTPUT:

```
1: http://www.google.es
2: http://stackoverflow.com
3: http://www.facebook.com
4: http://akinator.com/cea
5: 
6: 
7: http://www.ufo.es/
8: http:/(dU[~
9: (dU[~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data read in is stored in a local variable `data` which goes out of scope when `readFile` exits. This would be ok provided the data is copied into the node structure. Currently the node data pointer just points to the local variable storage.

Comment: To resolve this, if you change `p->web = web;` to `p->web = strdup(web);` it should work. (Strictly you should check that strdup doesn't return null as the memory has run out.)